# Extracting and Normalizing Nested JSON Data from CSV File using Python with Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

**Problem Description:**

I'm trying to extract data from a CSV file in Python using the Pandas library. However, the data in the CSV file is in a nested JSON format and the structure is malformed due to extra commas and characters. Here's an example of how the first few lines of the file look:

```
reviews
"[{'funny': '', 'posted': 'Posted November 5, 2011.', 'last_edited': '', 'item_id': '1250', 'helpful': 'No ratings yet', 'recommend': True, 'review': 'Simple yet with great replayability. In my opinion does ""zombie"" hordes and team work better than left 4 dead plus has a global leveling system. Alot of down to earth ""zombie"" splattering fun for the whole family. Amazed this sort of FPS is so rare.'}, {'funny': '', 'posted': 'Posted July 15, 2011.', 'last_edited': '', 'item_id': '22200', 'helpful': 'No ratings yet', 'recommend': True, 'review': 'It's unique and worth a playthrough.'}, {'funny': '', 'posted': 'Posted April 21, 2011.', 'last_edited': '', 'item_id': '43110', 'helpful': 'No ratings yet', 'recommend': True, 'review': 'Great atmosphere. The gunplay can be a bit chunky at times but at the end of the day this game is definitely worth it and I hope they do a sequel...so buy the game so I get a sequel!'}]"
"[{'funny': '', 'posted': 'Posted June 24, 2014.', 'last_edited': '', 'item_id': '251610', 'helpful': '15 of 20 people (75%) found this review helpful', 'recommend': True, 'review': 'I know what you think when you see this title ""Barbie Dreamhouse Party"" but do not be intimidated by it\'s title, this is easily one of my GOTYs. You don\'t get any of that cliche game mechanics that all the latest games have, this is simply good core gameplay. Yes, you can\'t 360 noscope your friends, but what you can do is show them up with your bad ♥♥♥ dance moves and put them to shame as you show them what true fashion and color combinations are.I know this game says for kids but, this is easily for any age range and any age will have a blast playing this.8/8'}, {'funny': '', 'posted': 'Posted September 8, 2013.', 'last_edited': '', 'item_id': '227300', 'helpful': '0 of 1 people (0%) found this review helpful', 'recommend': True, 'review': 'For a simple (it's actually not all that simple but it can be!) truck driving Simulator, it is quite a fun and relaxing game. Playing on simple (or easy?) its just the basic WASD keys for driving but (if you want) the game can be much harder and realistic with having to manually change gears, much harder turning, etc. And reversing in this game is a ♥♥♥♥♥, as I imagine it would be with an actual truck. Luckily, you don't have to reverse park it but you get extra points if you do cause it is bloody hard. But this is suprisingly a nice truck driving game and I had a bit of fun with it.'}, {'funny': '', 'posted': 'Posted November 29, 2013.', 'last_edited': '', 'item_id': '239030', 'helpful': '1 of 4 people (25%) found this review helpful', 'recommend': True, 'review': 'Very fun little game to play when your bored or as a time passer. Very gud. Do Recommend. pls buy'}]"
```

I'm struggling to normalize these data due to the incorrect structure and the additional characters present in the CSV file. How can I properly extract and normalize this data using Python and Pandas? Any guidance you can offer would be greatly appreciated!

use this code to get the "reviews" key which is the problem but it doesn't work

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

# Carga el archivo CSV en un DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('reviews_explotadas.csv')

# Define una función para corregir los diccionarios
def fix_dicts(row):
    try:
        # Corrige las comillas y demás caracteres en los diccionarios
        row = row.replace("'", '"').replace('""', '"')
        # Parsea el string JSON a un diccionario Python
        row = ast.literal_eval(row)
        return row
    except:
        return None

# Aplica la función a la columna que contiene los diccionarios
df['reviews'] = df['reviews'].apply(fix_dicts)

# Utiliza la función explode para dividir los diccionarios en filas separadas
df_exploded = df.explode('reviews').reset_index(drop=True)

# Muestra el DataFrame resultante
print(df_exploded.head())
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please take a moment to verify that my edits reflect your original question. Please pay particular attention to the example data and make sure it still accurately reflects your data.

Comment: Note that the core issue is that some of the reviews contain improperly escaped apostrophes. Technically you can do `ast.literal_eval(<your text>.replace("'s", "\\'s").replace("'t", "\\'t"))` but that only works as none of your keys start with s or t. The real solution is to fix your input somehow.